# Como instalar módulos de um projeto Python com Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Eu estou acostumado a trabalhar com JavaScript, e já é comum baixar um projeto do GitHub e executar o comando `yarn` para baixar todos os módulos que aquele projeto usa para que eu possa executar o projeto.

Porém, resolvi mexer com Flask e não estou entendendo como a instalação dos módulos funciona. O Flask também trabalha com módulos instalados como o `flask` e o `flask-restplus`, e quando eu envio meu código em Flask para o GitHub, nenhum dos módulos baixados são enviados. Até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu baixo o repositório em outro local, eu não sei como reinstalar os módulos utilizados naquele projeto.

Tem alguma maneira de reinstalar esses módulos ou eu teria que reinstalar um por um e criar uma nova venv local?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve instalar as dependências utilizando o pip (python index packages).

Em geral (isto é uma convenção) as dependências estão listadas em um arquivo, com o nome:

```
requirements.txt
```

Que também por convenção se localiza na `raiz do projeto`.

Desta forma ao baixar um projeto para instalar as dependências basta executar o comando:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Essas convenções não fazem parte de nenhuma pep específica, mas estão documentadas [no guia do mochileiro python](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Executando o comando acima, as dependências serão instaladas, fazendo com que você possa iniciar a aplicação.

#### Boas práticas relacionadas à criação de um novo ambiente

Ao clonar o projeto o ideal é usar o [`virtualenv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virtualenv.1.html) para criar um novo ambiente limpo (sem dependências externas) e a partir deste ambiente proceder para a instalação das dependências.

##### Criar o virtualenv

Para criar o ambiente virtual eu utilizo o programa virtualenv. Executando o seguinte comando:

```
virtualenv venv -p $(which python3)
```

Este comando vai criar um diretório de nome `venv` (pode escolher o nome) na pasta em que foi executado, neste caso o diretório em que estou (cwd) que utilizando  os binários do python3.

Obs: a partir da versão do python3.3 foi incluído um mecanismo para criação de ambientes virtuais incorporado ao próprio Python3. Se este for o caso não precisa ter o virtualenv instalado e para criar o ambiente virtual, basta executar o [`comando`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

```
python3 -m venv </caminho/para/novo/ambiente/virtual>
```

Mais informações podem ser encontradas na [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)

##### Ativando o virtualenv

Para ativar o ambiente virtual, utilizando o terminal (bash, sh), devemos executar o comando:

```
source venv/bin/activate #para linux
#para Windows é necessário executar scripts/activate.bat
```

Após ativar o ambiente virtual podemos proceder para a instalação das dependências.
Em ambientes baseados em Linux um indicativo de que o ambiente virtual está ativo é que na linha de execução do shell aparece o nome do ambiente entre parêntesis.

Como no exemplo:

```
(venv) user@ubuntu:~$ #<-- virtualenv ativo
user@ubuntu:~$ #<-- virtualenv não está ativo, isso é o shell padrão.
```

##### Instalando as depedências

Após ativar o virtualenv agora basta instalar as dependências, com o comando:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Resumo

1. clonar o projeto:

   `git clone <endereço do projeto em algum repositório>`
2. Entrar na pasta do projeto clonado
3. Criar o ambiente virtual:

   `virtualenv venv -p $(which python3)`
4. ativar o ambiente virtual:

   `source venv bin/activate`
5. instalar as dependências:

   `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Muito muito muito obrigado, eu me matei pra achar isso na internet, mas sem uma referência foi dificil, valeuzão!!